# jQuery matched set to string

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, serialization

I need to serialize a matched set so it's values can be passed to my rails app.

The matched set code is (returns the parent div of every uninitialized select element):

```
jQuery('select').filter(function(index){
     return jQuery(this).val() == 0;}).closest('div')
```

for serialization I really only need the id of each matched element so I tried:

```
jQuery('select').filter(function(index){
     return jQuery(this).val() == 0;}).closest('div').attr('id')
```

Unfortunatly `attr()` only works on the first element in a matched set.

Since the resulting javascript will be sent via rails' `remote_function :with`  I believe javascript can only be one statement.

How can a matched set be serialized, or to-string'd?

Comment: So, you want a single string containing all of the selected divs' IDs? ... separated by commas?

Comment: I'm a little fuzzy on what you mean by: "I believe javascript can only be one statement"

Comment: @morgancodes, for rails the javascript gets passed as a string.  When I tried a passing more than one statement i.e ( var test_var; jQuery(...) )it fails silently.

Comment: The "only one statement" thing sounds kind of fishy to me. Is this javascript being loaded by the creation of a new script tag? Or is it an ajax request that's being eval'd? In either case, the browser shouldn't just fail silently, it should complian. I'd just make sure that was a real limitation that other people experience as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For variety's sake, here's an answer using `map`:

```
result = jQuery('select')
    .filter( function(index){
        return jQuery(this).val() == 0;
    })
    .closest('div')
    .map( function(){
        return this.id;
    })
    .get()       // stop here if you want an array
    .join(',');  // or here if you want a string
```

Answer (score 1):

For *even more* variety's sake, here's one with less looping involved:

```
var idString = $('select').map(function(){
    var select = $(this);
    return select.val() == 0 ? select.closest('div').attr('id') : null;
}).get().join(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = [];

jQuery('select').filter(function(index){
  return jQuery(this).val() == 0;
}).closest('div').each( function() {
  result.push(this.id);
});

var resultStr = result.join(',');
```